# Parallel.Foreach closed before finish the thread before it's completed

Tags: c#

I have a C# console application that's send request over internet and get the response, i'm using parallel.Foreach.

When i'm using small requests sent it works fine, but if i'm send a lot of requests there are nothing result, after tracing the problem i found that the thread exit before finish and print the result:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int threads = Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllText(@"threads.txt"));

        var workItems = new List<object>();


        foreach (string user in File.ReadLines("x.txt"))
        {


            foreach (string pass in File.ReadLines("y.txt"))
            {


                foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("z.txt"))
                {

                    workItems.Add(new object[] { line, user, pass });


                }
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
        }
        var opts = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads };
        var results = Parallel.ForEach(workItems, opts, tesTConn );

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit.");
        Console.Read();


    }

    //string domain, int port, string username, string password

    public static void tesTConn(object state)
    {

    }
```

Comment: "the thread", do you mean the main thread? no exceptions? And please try to remove the try/catch block in your method that swallows exceptions, if all the methods throw an exception then the foreach will be done quickly, and you will be none the wiser.

Comment: As an example, you're trying to append to a file from each such method, if another parallel method is currently doing the same, the second method will throw an exception because the file is in use. You need to safeguard against this kind of use of shared resources. The first step of your troubleshooting job should still be to get rid of your empty catch block as any exceptions being thrown will be silently swallowed, and most likely you get an exception that will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Can you tell us the purpose of this program?

Comment: Thanks  Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, the problem is not in writing to file as its not required for me its just for testing, the issue is the process not finished in each item in foreach

Comment: the program purpose is to secure voip servers from external attack this is small component of the security solution we are working on to test the server security

Comment: Did you remove the empty catch block?

Comment: yes i'm remove it and still nothing changed

Comment: @MohamedAldanaf have you tried running my answer? Make sure the basic pattern works then slowly add your code until something breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.
(Note, I'm exploiting .net 4.7.1 for the anon touple types)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var work = new List<(string, string, string)> { ("a", "a", "a"), ("a", "a", "b"), ("a", "a", "c"), ("a", "a", "d"), ("a", "a", "e"), ("a", "a", "f"), ("a", "a", "g") };
        var threads = 3;
        var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads };
        Parallel.ForEach(work, opts, Test);


        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Test((string, string, string) item)
    {
        //Do work....
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Item1}:{item.Item2}:{item.Item3}");
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
a:a:c
a:a:e
a:a:a
a:a:d
a:a:f
a:a:b
a:a:g
Done!
```

Comment: From looking at your code again, it seems like your Test method's arguments, and work list type, might be declared incorrectly.